# Particle-antiparticle duality and special relativity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, antimatter, duality

I was reading through Zee's *QFT in a Nutshell* and I reached the end of the second chapter, where Zee discusses the similarities between Compton scattering and electron-positron annihilation. While I understood for the most part the arguments for the fact that antiparticles have nothing to do with going back in time and negative energies, Zee ends the chapter with a paragraph where he brings up special relativity to further nail down the point. But this confuses me more than it makes the point clear. I copy here the paragraph:

> Compton scattering offers a context for constructing a nice heuristic argument. Think
> of the process in spacetime. We have redrawn figure II.8.1a in figure II.8.3: the electron is
> hit by the photon at the point $x$, propagates to the point $y$, and emits a photon. We have
> assumed implicitly that $(y_0 − x_0) > 0$, since we don’t know what propagating backward
> in time means. (If the reader knows how to build a time machine, let me know.) But
> special relativity tells us that another observer moving by (along the 1-direction say) would
> see the time difference $(y_0 − x_0) = \cosh\varphi(y_0 − x_0) − \sinh\varphi(y_1 − x_1)$, which could be
> negative for large enough boost parameter $\varphi$, provided that $(y_1 − x_1) > (y_0 − x_0)$, that
> is, if the separation between the two spacetime points $x$ and $y$ were spacelike. Then this
> observer would see the field disturbance propagating from $y$ to $x$. Since we see negative
> electric charge propagating from $x$ to $y$, the other observer must see positive electric
> charge propagating from $y$ to $x$. Without special relativity, as in nonrelativistic quantum
> mechanics, we simply write down the Schrodinger equation for the electron and that is
> that. Special relativity allows different observers to see different time ordering and hence
> opposite charges flowing toward the future.

He says that for spacelike separated events, the events can be seen in reverse order. Fairly enough, mathematically. But are spacelike separated events physical? (as they basically allow, at least so it seems to me, a reversal of cause and effect).

And furthermore, how are spacelike separated events related to Compton scattering, for example? My guess is that the 2 vertices in the Feynman diagram could, maybe, not be restricted to being timelike separated. But then, wouldn't this mean that the virtual particle can move faster than light, which would make it possible for the electron and photon to interact at some point, and then separate at another point that is farther than light could reach (which sounds a bit SF to me, as a succession of such processes would allow any particle to overall move faster than light).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But are spacelike separated events physical? (as they basically allow, at least so it seems to me, a reversal of cause and effect).

Obviously you mean, "is traversing a spacelike separation physical?" For real particles, of course not. I'll try not to make controversial statements about the "virtual particles" in Zee's preferred formalism, but the crucial observation is that his use of Fourier transforms identifies dummy integration variables in $\Bbb R^4$ that aren't subject to the same causality constraints as real particles' four-displacements & four-momenta. In particular, the integration range has to be all of $\Bbb R^4$ for the Dirac-delta-is-integral-of-complex-exponential trick to work.

> the virtual particle can move faster than light, which would make it possible for the electron and photon to...

Suppose two real particles exert a force on each other by exchanging a virtual one. If this worked like one person throwing a ball at another on a frictionless skating rink, the force would have to be repulsive. The fact that attractive forces admit a particle exchange explanation gives a simple proof of something we can verify with the aforementioned Fourier treatment: a virtual particle doesn't obey the usual dynamical equations for its $4$-momentum, and in particular the $3$-momentum doesn't have to point in the "direction of propagation" (which, regardless of your take on virtual particles, is from one real particle to another).

A further surprise, which addresses your confusion, is that $p^2<0$ doesn't imply the "speed" of propagation exceeds $c$. (Again, the quotation is around a phrase we can uncontroversially identify in terms of the retardation inherent in one particle's influence on another.)

Again, these facts are unavoidable consequences of the aforementioned integration range.

> a succession of such processes would allow any particle to overall move faster than light

As I said, unlike their virtual counterparts, real particles can't "cheat" the rules of SR you learned before QFT.